# Retrieve an object with a given attribute from a deep hierarchy

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a hierarchy of objects that can have children. All objects have a unique `id`. I need to retrieve an object from anywhere in this hierarchy given only the `id`. For example, the hierarchy may look like this:

```
var hierarchy = [
  {id: 1, children: [
    {id: 7},
    {id: 8}
  ]},
  {id: 2},
  {id: 3, children: [
    {id: 9},
    {id: 10, children: [
      {id: 11},
      {id: 12},
      {id: 13}
    ]}
  ]},
  {id: 4},
  {id: 5},
  {id: 6, children: [
    {id: 14}
  ]}
];
```

And the function call would look something like this:

```
retrieveObjectById(10, hierarchy);
// => {id: 10, children: [...]}
```

I tried writing a function using Array.filter that would get recursively called on an element's children when encountered, but it returns the ancestors, as well.

Comment: You should include what've you tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea to solve those problems is generally to use a recursive function like this :

```
function deepFind(obj, id) {
    if (obj.id==id) return obj;
    if (obj.children) {
       for (var i=0; i<obj.children.length; i++) {
           var o = deepFind(obj.children[i], id);
           if (o) return o;
       }
    }
}
```

As your root level object hasn't the same structure, you could either loop in `hierarchy` or make it similar :

```
var myObject = deepFind({children:hierarchy}, 10);
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/erugec/2/edit)